# How do you include png files in a Swift object from a JSON file?

Tags: json, swift, codable

My phone is parsing data from an Xcode JSON file to objects from a Codable model and passing data to watch using WCSession. Everything works great.

JSON files only include URLs/paths to images not actual images obviously so how do I add images from my Xcode project directory as part of the same JSON?

I would add a local path to the JSON file pointing to a set of images? Then add a property `let profile : UIImage` to my data object? Will it be a separate struct data object? Would it be easier to use dummy images from live URLs? How would I actually pass the image to a UIImage/WKInterfaceImage in a table?

```
    struct MessageObject : Codable {

    var title : String
    //...

    enum MessageKeys: String, CodingKey {
        //...
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MessageKeys.self)

        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        //...
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: MessageKeys.self)

        //...
    }       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. I am already using that API successfully. I want to add separate images from my project directory. But include them in the same data model.

Comment: Which of the two answers would most represent real-world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing the `Data` of the image?

Your `Codable` model could include a property like this:

```
var imageData: Data
```

And then you could set it like this:

```
imageData = someUIImage.pngData()!
```

When you encode it, the JSON will become something like:

```
{"imageData":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAABxpRE9UAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAWxzQ72oAAAAnSURBVCgVYjhzeOX\/\/1+uYGCQOAgz4JPEqgCmE0SDNKOYgC4JUgAAAAD\/\/ytw2SEAAAAnSURBVGP4\/+XKfxA+c3glHMPEQDQDPkmwAlw6YaYwwBTABJBpkBwAoM\/kGdRps6oAAAAASUVORK5CYII="}
```

To get an image from the data, just do:

```
UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to create the JSON file beforehand (not on the fly) and your images are not meant to change, then you could convert your images to base64 encoded strings in a site like [this one](https://www.base64-image.de) and then add those strings to the JSON file:

```
{
    "image1": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHL..."    
    "image2": "G2qoAEpaUQIZD4QYT4A62AHzQUqOiTgsgPEBCJIKAVJF..."    
    ...
}
```

Creating a Data object and eventually a UIImage for each base64 encoded image later on would be similar to this:

```
if let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: img1Base64) {        
    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        imageView.image = image
    }        
}
```